# Compiled node.js module not getting correct library path when copied to different machines

Tags: node.js, linux, db2, node-gyp

My problem is a little complicated but I'll try:
I have a node.js application that needs to be completely prebuilt and bundled alongside standalone node.js (specifically 4.4.5 LTS), zipped and deployed to **offline** CentOS 6/7 machines, meaning I cannot do `npm install`, and no gcc/g++/python so I cannot do things like `node-gyp rebuild`.

Everything is working correctly except this module: [ibm_db](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db).
It's compiled with node-gyp after downloading the db2 cli drivers, but basically it's supposed to work like the regular DB2 client except all its dynamic libraries, binaries etc. are inside the module path itself (node_modules/ibm_db/installer/clidriver).

If I deploy the bundle (which includes all node modules in the tarball, including ibm_db) to another machine, it's probably going to sit on a different path from the machine on which I built the bundle. When I try to run the app like this: `./node app.js` (here `node` is a symlink to the standalone node binary inside the unpacked bundle) i get this error:

```
Error: libdb2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now, I can clearly see that `libdb2.so.1` is inside `node_modules/ibm_db/installer/clidriver/lib` but the paths in `bindings.gyp` all use the original paths on the build machine which don't match, so I assume this is where the problem lies.

I can easily just add that path with `ldconfig` and it would work, however the user profile installing the app will not have superuser access so it's not a real option.

I tried setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but node.js deletes this entry from `process.env` on startup, and even if I programmatically set it like `process.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH='...';` it doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there any way to modify the library path for a compiled module without recompiling/rebuilding it? If it's possible I would assume that would be the easiest solution, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Have you considered using a Docker container to deploy your application? Seems like a perfect use case.

Comment: You probably followed these instructions http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.javascript.doc/doc/t0061583.html. Have you considered raising an issue on the GitHub repo for ibm_db?